# Bootstrap nav-bar brand centered on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to make a responsive webpage and for the navbar I used Bootstrap and I have some question about the brand setting. what should I do to make the navbar brand on left on desktop and center on mobile?
I already made an navbar.

here are is my code in html.

```
<body id="mypage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50" style="background-color:bisque">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
    <div class="container-fluid navbar-left">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:59842/NNC.html">
            logo
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="background-color:black">
                    yes<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="background-color:black">
                    no<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">yes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">yes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">yes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  nav a.navbar-brand{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 766px) {
  nav a.navbar-brand{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
  <div class="container-fluid navbar-left">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:59842/NNC.html">
            logo
        </a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="background-color:black">
                    yes<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="background-color:black">
                    no<span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">yes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">yes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">yes</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```